# Why is it okay for an enum to have two different names with the same numeric value?

Tags: c#, enums

I just discovered a subtle bug where I had an enum with two names unintentially sharing the same numeric value (in this case red=10 and crimson=10). I'm a bit surprised this isn't a syntax error.

```
public enum Colour
{
    Red=10,
    Blue=11,
    Green=12,
    Crimson=10
}
// Debug.Write(Colour.Red==Colour.Crimson) outputs True
```

Is there any real world reason why this behaviour might be a useful or do think it should be a syntax error?

Comment: I thought I was so clever for thinking to ask this over three years after it was asked originally.

Comment: See the MSDN guidelines for enum design: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229058.aspx

In the spirit of these, I'd say that even though it's technically possible, it's probably not advised.

Comment: @MrBoJangles, then I was going to ask the same thing again 16 months after you.

Comment: I was trying to create a `Dictionary<ExternalEnum, TValue>` where `ExternalEnum` is in an external assembly I can't modify. The dictionary needed to have a value for *every* enum value in `ExternalEnum`, but two values in `ExternalEnum` have the same numeric value. I then got an ArgumentException because (I think) the dictionary is keyed on the numeric value behind the scenes - I've since had to exclude the duplicated value from the dictionary.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
public enum Colour
{
    Red=10,
    Rouge=10,
    Blue=11,
    Bleu=11,
    Green=12,
    Vert=12,
    Black=13,
    Noir=13
}
```

Comment: Very concise and effective answer.

Comment: And how would you use that? In a multilingual programming team, each member choosing his own constants?

Comment: I'm at a loss as to how this is an effective answer.

Comment: @Henk Holterman this is NOT an answer about a multilingual programming team. This is an answer which indicates a "real world" reason why you might use two different words for the same value in an enum.

Comment: @Robin: Like @Noldorin, I fail to see how this is useful. Can you give an example using it?

Comment: @Henk Holterman: No, I can't give an example of using it. Who in their right mind would create an enum with multi-lingual colours?!? This is an example of how you can use synonyms to represent the same values. Red and Rouge in this instant are identical and therefore should have the same value.

Comment: Robin, OK, but the OQ was why it wasn't disallowed so we were  looking for an example of _why_ one should use this, not so much for _how_.

Comment: `One should use it if one needs to use it.` Example : I am working on a program that uses the current and some previous frames for video processing. I store the previous images in an array and I use `enums` for indexing. In one mode of operation I need `0` to be the previous image and in another mode I need `0` to be the left up image, `1` - right up, etc., and it is possible that I might need 0 to be some other image in a future implementation of another mode. In this case I use `enums` instead of `magic numbers` for indexing and I believe it will be cleaner that way.

Answer (score 31):

Beware!  If your `enum` has multiple elements with the same value, you may get unexpected results when you use `Enum.Parse()`.  Doing so will arbitrarily return the first element that has the requested value.  For example, if you have `enum Car { Ford = 1, Chevy = 1, Mazda = 1}`, then `(Car)Enum.Parse(typeof(Car), "1")` will return `Car.Ford`.  While that might be useful (I'm not sure why it would be), in most situations it's probably going to be confusing (especially for engineers maintaining the code) or easily overlooked when problems arise.

Comment: Thank you for your first answer on SO, and it's a good one.  May I suggest editing the text to add some additional white space and, in particular, to use markdown to highlight the code fragments?  The easiest way to do the latter is to either `surround the text` with backtick (`) or use the code quote button in the formatting bar.  I suspect that your upvote count may even rise if it's a little easier to read.   Good luck.

Comment: That example can equally be said to return `Car.Mazda` as well, because `Car.Mazda == Car.Ford`.  The choice of the particular name does not happen inside `Enum.Parse`, but rather inside `ToString` which was probably used to study the `Enum.Parse` behavior.

Answer (score 20):

I have seen that this feature is sometimes used for a "default" value:

```
public enum Scope
{
    Transient,
    Singleton,
    Default=Transient
}
```

But pay attention, this is only sugar for the user of your enum. Just because it is called *Default* it does not mean that it is the initial value.

Answer (score 11):

Enums are used like constans and you definitely can have two constants with the same value which are used in the same places. It can be so because of 3rd party API, because of backward compatibility ot just because of business rules.

Answer (score 7):

Enum is Enumeration of constant variables, and you can have two items with the same value,there is no reason to be a syntax error I think, however, this will cause compile error in this code

```
switch(c)
{
  Colour.Red:
     break;
  Colour.Crimson:
     break;
  ...
}
```

Comment: It's worth knowing this. It's a reason not to deliberately use share names.

Comment: Agreed; two names with the same value is not an error. If you'd like to avoid it, do not specify the numeric values.

Answer (score 7):

[From the c# language spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664599):

Multiple enum members may share the same associated value. The example

```
enum Color 
{
    Red,
    Green,
    Blue,
    Max = Blue
}
```

shows an enum in which two enum members—Blue and Max—have the same associated value.

In this case you could check for MyColor == Color.Max which would be useful is some circumstances.

Comment: Max is an example of a sentinal value. This is not recommended per the MSDN design guidelines for enumerations because it violates the separation of concerns between the raw value and it's state. If the need ever arises to change what is considered Max, any references expecting Max to always equal Blue would need to be fixed.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a syntax error. All an `enum` does is enumerate a series of constants in a strongly-typed fashion.

Thus, if a developer mistypes (as in your example), as far as the CLR is concerned, that's a perfectly valid case. The CLR assumes that the developer knows what he's doing, and why he elected to do so.

As for real-world cases, I can't come up with any on the spur-of-the-moment, but I'm still certain that there probably are occasions where it'd be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Sure there is, though it's perhaps not too common. If there is an entity/value that is commonly known under two different names, then that is a good reason.

The scenario you have presented is perhaps one such case. An even better one, straight from the BCL, is the [`System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messageboxicon.aspx) enum; the `Stop`, `Error`, and `Hand` members all have the same description and indeed the same value. `Asterisk` and `Information` are also identical, as suggested by the comments:

```
Asterisk    The message box contains a symbol consisting of a lowercase letter i in a circle.
Information The message box contains a symbol consisting of a lowercase letter i in a circle.
```

Hopefully this should give you a good idea of appropiate scenarios (your own probably being one).

Answer (score 1):

It's fine. You could have two values that are different from the point of view of the user of an API, but functionally can be treated as the same value.

Answer (score 1):

Using by named value as opposed to the actual value is root.  Suppose you have French, English etc. with the same value.  This is the root of enum to me.

Answer (score 1):

It is sometimes recommended (although *not* recommended by MS for C#! - see Salaros's comment) to include a lower and upper bound in your enum such as

```
public enum Colour
{
    LowBound=10,
    Red=10,
    Rouge=10,
    Blue=11,
    Bleu=11,
    Green=12,
    Vert=12,
    Black=13,
    Noir=13,
    UpperBound=13
}
```

For the purposes of validation/iterating through each possible setting. Though I have a feeling that .Net may provide a facility for this :)

Comment: The end of enumeration is a bound itself and you can iterate it in order of declaration:
foreach(Foos foo in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Foos)))

Actually it's recommended to avoid sentinel enumeration values (LowBound, UpperBound)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229058%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: I was giving an example of where multiple items can share a value. In some languages you can't iterate an enum with foreach. Hardly deserving of a -1 but never mind!

Comment: We are talking about C# and not "other" languages, so if you teach somebody to code against the official specifications you deserve -1.
I this way C# newbies won't learn wrong thins on C#.
Anyway keep in mind that -1 is applied to both accounts, so this is not trolling: I'm just sacrificing my points in order to improve stackoverflow.. this is what we all supposed to do.

Comment: Yes it's a fair point. I was only being bemoaning the -1 for the sake of moaning. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is valid and allows one to refer same value with different names. 
Beware this works well oneway. You may get inconsistent results if you are converting from int/string to enum or while formatting strings.

Eg:

```
public enum Colour
{
    Red=10,
    Blue=11,
    Green=12,
    Crimson=10
}
Colour myColor = Colour.Crimson;
Console.WriteLine("Crimson is {0}", myColor.ToString());
```

Output:

```
Crimson is Red
```

Answer (score 1):

This example will show why this is useful. When you are working on public library, which is dedicated to public use, naming same things in different way may be useful.

```
public enum GestureType
{
Touch = 1,
Tap = 1,
DoubleTouch = 2,
DoubleTap = 2,
Swipe = 3,
Slide = 3,
...
}
```

When different words have same meaning in some situations it has sense, to name them. When parsing, it always return good value in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently working on a project where this is actually a usefull feature.

```cs
public enum State
{
    NotTransmitted = 0,
    Deleted = 0,
    Transmitted = 1,
    Deactivated = 1,
    Activated = 2
}
```

The states NotTransmitted and Deleted are programmatically identical and it does not matter for the software which is the actual case. In both cases the software will have to f.e. transmit this item to a receiver.

That being said, it is far more intuitive for a programmer to set the state to "Deleted" after deleting it than to set it to "NotTransmitted". The same goes for setting it to "Transmitted" after transmitting it over setting it to "Deactivated".

So in short it enhances readability of code.

Answer (score 1):

#### How about with `Obsolete`?

We had a case where, for whatever reason, we needed to change the name of the enum's values in a shipped library. I believe their usage changed slightly and they were relabeled in the backing datastore.

You could argue for a number of other options, like obsolete the whole enum and add a second, or use new values for the new options (there are reasons, but I hear you), but I don't think I can argue why any are inherently "right-er" at this point.

In any event...

```
public enum Colour
{
    [Obsolete("The colour Red will soon be replaced with Crimson. Please update your usage.")]
    Red = 10,
    Blue = 11,
    Green = 12,
    Crimson = 10
}
```

Had we not been able to use the same value twice, we would not have been able to make a name `Obsolete` like this between versions.

But [Bill's warning holds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19168699/1028230).

```
Console.WriteLine(Colour.Red);
Console.WriteLine(Colour.Crimson);
```

Those both output `Red` to the console. To quote Maude, "You can imagine where it goes from here."

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the same thing in a .net TWAIN wrapper - it allows all the TWAIN message codes to be stored in one big enum, but it does make things a bit confusing at first.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are many uses for re-using the same number. To give a new example, say you have a ranking system which will ensure that objects of a particular class (Parent) are created before other classes that are dependent on it (Children), you may have some children who are in the same 'tier' and it does not matter which one is created first. In the example below, Parent would be created first, Child 1, 2, or 3 next, then last would be Child4. If this were viewed as a tree diagram, any items with the same number would be 'siblings'.

```
public enum ObjectRanks
{
    Parent = 0,
    Child1 = 1,
    Child2 = 1,
    Child3 = 1,
    Child4 = 2
}
```

Although I can see your point of view in that this could be easy to do by mistake. In that case it would be handy if visual studio had an option to enable warnings which would let it compile but would raise a warning if the same number was used twice.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it would be useful for field mapping, for example (in LinqPad):

```
void Main()
{
    ((FieldName)Enum.Parse(typeof(FieldName), "Name", true)).ToString().Dump();
    ((FieldName)Enum.Parse(typeof(FieldName), "TaskName", true)).ToString().Dump();
    ((FieldName)Enum.Parse(typeof(FieldName), "IsActive", true)).ToString().Dump();
    ((FieldName)Enum.Parse(typeof(FieldName), "TaskIsActive", true)).ToString().Dump();
}

public enum FieldName
{
    Name,
    TaskName = Name,
    IsActive,
    TaskIsActive = IsActive
}
```

The aim is use the shorter of the names, however the results from Parse or TryParse are not consistent and this code outputs:

```
TaskName
TaskName
IsActive
IsActive
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public enum SortBy
    {
        Ascending = 0,
        Descending = 1,
        Asc = 0,
        Desc = 1
    }
```

This is why this solution was useful for me

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's code analysis includes rule [CA1069: Enums should not have duplicate values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1069).

**However**, that rule only applies to explicitly assigning the same numeric literal to two different names of the enum.  It does not apply to assigning a previous name to a new name.  The [Rule Description section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1069#rule-description) says (emphasis mine):

> Every enum member should either have a unique constant value **or be explicitly assigned with a prior member in the enum** to indicate explicit intent of sharing value.

As I understand it, Microsoft is explicitly saying that it is OK to have two enum names for the same value, but instead of using a duplicate number like this...

```csharp
public enum Colour
{
    Red=10,
    Blue=11,
    Green=12,
    Crimson=10 // Duplicate specified with number.
}
```

...it is less error prone to explicitly equate a name with a previous name...

```csharp
public enum Colour
{
    Red=10,
    Blue=11,
    Green=12,
    Crimson=Red // Duplicate specified with name.
}
```

Of course, there are still the issues with conversion to a string, as discussed in other answers.