# Enum.Parse method returns a different enum member than the one passed into it as the parameter

Tags: c#, enums

I expect the following call to the Parse method to return the enum member EN_CA but it returns EN instead.

```
Enum.Parse(LanguageType, "EN_CA", true);
```

where:

```
enum LanguageType
{
  EN = 0,
  EN_CA = 0,
  FR = 1
}
```

It seems like the Parse method just grabs the first member that maps to the value of the parameter that is passed into it.The Parse method seems to be loosing information during the conversion from string to enum member. Changing the order of EN_CA and EN would make the above call to return EN_CA but that is not going to solve the problem since it would cause a similar issue when calling the method for "EN".

**Additional context related information:** In my code, the LanguageType Enum is represent the index for a dictionary and these indices are used for localizing the language.

Does anyone have any idea of how to map two enum member to the same value while being able to get proper member from Enum.Parse? Do I just need to implement my own version of Enum.Parse which doesn't collapse the members with the same value into one?

Comment: Why are you using the same value for `EN` and `EN_CA`?

Comment: the integer value 0 is mapped to some index and I would wantto get both EN and EN_CA to map to the same index. the index 0 in my code brings in the english translation for some dictionary; so I'd like to get myDictionary[LanguageType.EN] and myDictionary[LanguageType.EN_CA] point to the same thing.

Comment: it is valid but makes your code not working by design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is how I fixed my problem:

I was not able to find a clean fix for the problem by getting Enum.Parse method return what I was expecting it to.(please see the note*)

My fix was to apply `GroupBy(LanguageIndex)` on the resulting dictionary which had its index duplicated and therefore throwing an exception. Since I wanted EN_CA and EN to have the same value in the enum that gave me what I was looking for without throwing an exception.

I can see that my fix is not an actual answer to the question that I initially asked, ignoring the context; though I though it might still be applicable to other contexts with a similar issue.

**note*** : I could have implemented my own version of Enum.Parse - Please see **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20388436/enum-parse-method-returns-a-different-enum-member-than-the-one-passed-into-it-as/20388924#20388924)** answer for an alternative implementation -  but that required me to put smelly hardcoded stuff into my code, so I just gave up on fixing the Parse method.

Answer (score 3):

An enum member is distinct from other enum members if and *only* if it has a different value.  Effectively the members of the enumeration are named constants, with no real distinction between them other than the value they hold.

In your `LanguageType` enum you have two labels for the same value, and no way to distinguish them.  Try this:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} == {1} ? {2}", 
    LanguageType.EN.ToString(), 
    LanguageType.EN_CA.ToString(),
    LanguageType.EN == LanguageType.EN_CA);
```

The output is:

```
EN == EN ? True
```

The same thing happens when you assign `LanguageType.EN_CA` to a variable, then examine the variable later to see what it contains.  What you get is `LanguageType.EN`.

The key here is that the *value* of the member is all-important in most instances, with the *position* of the member being the tie-breaker during collisions.  When two members have the same value the member that is declared first is the one that you will see whenever you do string conversions, including when you examine the value in the IDE.

So in effect you have a value `LanguageType.EN_CA` that is only an alias to the value `LanguageType.EN`.

While I can think of a couple of cute uses for this - like parsing incoming data that has multiple representations for the same value - it is really quite a terrible thing to do in *most* real-world environments, *especially* if you want to be able to do fully symmetric serialization/deserialization.

Now, as to your localization `Dictionary`...

It costs very little to store the same class object multiple times in a Dictionary, since class objects are stored by reference.  Assuming you have a `Localization` class, the following code is not particularly inefficient in terms of storage:

```
enum LanguageType
{
    EN, EN_CA, EN_US, EN_GB, EN_AU, FR
}


Dictionary<LanguageType, Localization> localizations = new Dictionary<LanguageType, Localization>();

localizations[LanguageType.EN] = new Localization("EN");
localizations[LanguageType.EN_CA] = localizations[LanguageType.EN];
localizations[LanguageType.EN_US] = localizations[LanguageType.EN];
localizations[LanguageType.EN_GB] = localizations[LanguageType.EN];
localizations[LanguageType.EN_AU] = localizations[LanguageType.EN];
```

Even if the `Localization` object contains a huge collection of resources, the above code only ever creates one instance of it.  You get distinct values for the `LanguageType` members, and the `Dictionary` does the mappings for you.

Comment: This comes down to rebuilding by hand things that are already present in the .Net runtime.

Comment: @flup how so?  If you are just talking about the fact that we're discussing localization then you are focusing too narrowly.  What if the enum was called `SupplierType` and the dictionary held `PaymentTerms` objects?  Would that be reimplementing something built into .NET?  If so, perhaps you could explain a little better.

Comment: The context is given in the question and it is that of internationalization.

Comment: @flup The question is about enums.  It just happens that the *details* of the question are about localization.  The enum aspect has much wider scope and should be addressed as such.  And unless you *know* that Greenish is *only* using this for holding information that the .NET localization code can support directly, you can't make any true determination.  I'm not trying to be rude, but answering the question that was actually asked seems to be the important thing.

Comment: On the other hand, we mustn't creatively assist him in hammering the square peg into the round hole *cheerful* Anyways, plenty suggestions made, he'll get a full enough picture of the possible solutions. Sorry if I upset you, this is not intended.

Comment: Not offended or upset, was just a little confused at the objection is all :P

Answer (score 2):

You defined `0` twice in your enum - this will not work. Each value has to be unique or how else would an enum recognize its values - it is actually stored as integer.

Change it to:

```
enum LanguageType
{
  EN = 0,
  EN_CA = 1,
  FR = 2
}
```

**EDIT**:

As pointed out by Greenish, you can define multiple names for the same value which acts as a sort of an alias. Using both or multiple names return the same value. If you try to get the string value from an integer value, you will get the first value defined for that integer.

In your case, you cannot achieve what you need using enums. You should probably build your own custom class to achieve that.

Comment: this is a valid way of defining enums. please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150753/why-is-it-okay-for-an-enum-to-have-two-different-names-with-the-same-numeric-val)

Comment: @Greenish True, I'll add it to the answer. But it doesn't change the OP's problem.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood it somewhat at the beginning. Is the key of your dictionary `int`? If it is, it's already working fine, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Enums basically are named integers. And it is possible to assign different names for a single number (as in your example for 0).

`Enum.Parse` searching for a first correct instance - and here you have a valid name as `0 == 0`. So the solution is to change your numbers (or even just get rid of them as they are 0, 1, 2)

```
enum LanguageType
{
  EN,
  EN_CA,
  FR
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought of a way but it's messy fragile and naff. There again it illustrates the hole you have dug for yourself..

```
int index = Enum.GetNames(typeof(LanguageType)).indexof("EN_CA")
```

will give you 1

then something like

```
switch(index)
{
  case 0 : return LanguageType.EN;
  case 1 : return LangaugeType.EN_CA;
  case 2 : return LanguageType.FR;
  default : // throw some useful exception maybe
   break
}
```

will return the member you want.

Horrible isn't it?

`Enum.GetValues(typeof(LanguageType))` would return [0,0,1] and using `indexof` 0 on it is of course 0, which is why Parse is giving you the result it is.

Comment: Just thought you could proably attck the maintenance issue around the switch statement by decorating the enum members with attributes and using those as your string representations. It would be polishing a turd though.

Comment: Hey Tony, I believe your suggested solution would work fine; though I wouldn't want to add hardcoded stuff to my code and make it smelly.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The `=0` specifies the representation of the enum's value in the underlying type (int). You've given both `EN` and `EN_CA` the same representation, namely 0, so now they've effectively become two labels for the same value.

`Enum.Parse` returns this value and it'll equal both labels.

The underlying problem is that you're trying to code a hierarchical concept, into a flat enum. For some purposes all english speaking cultures should be treated equal, for other purposes you'd like to distinguish between them.

The solution, I think, is to use the [already present mechanisms for localizing your application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6270d0z%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), in particular [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87k6sx8t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) should replace your enum and [Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f45fce5x%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) your lookup dictionary.

---

I was a little surprised that this use of enum is allowed :)
But the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664599%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) explicitly states it is valid and gives an example of how it can be useful:

```
enum Color 
{
   Red,
   Green,
   Blue,
   Max = Blue
}
```

Comment: It's perfectly reasonable to allow two names for the same value, after all enums are simply a human comprehensible representation of a magic number. As you point out though as soon as the compiler maps from value to the magic number, value is lost.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson As long as your code never uses `ToString` or `Parse` on the values, then there is no *overt* problem.  As soon as you do a string conversion - during (de-)serialization for example - you lose information.  Aliasing for convenience is fine, so long as you are aware that problems *can* arise from it.

Comment: @Corey no, the problem is already there, since EN == EN_CA, regardless of string representation. The enum labels are equal too.

Comment: @flup I thought it was clear from my post and comments that I agree, that having multiple enum members with the same value is problematic.  But there are (relatively) legitimate reasons to do so.

Comment: @Corey that's what I said, or at least what I thought I said. name to value only maps one way as one value has two names. Not just Parser and ToString, LanguageType lt = LanguageType.EN_CA; if (lt = LanguageType.EN) ... won't work as advertised either.

Comment: @Corey it is allowed, and for legitimate reasons. It need not be problematic. But the important thing to realise is that the information is not lost during conversion, it's already lost in the declaration of the enum.

Comment: @flup Please read my answer below.  I am well aware of this, and my comment here in no way indicates that I think otherwise.